# UpdateSourceTrigger не срабатывает, хотя поле для Binding меняется

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот кусок кода MainWindow. На биндинг текста стоит поле MyTitle из вьмодели.

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="35" Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}">
        <TextBox Foreground="Aquamarine" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=MyTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
```

При запуске приложения привязка работает. Вот ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel<T> : BaseIPOViewModel<T>
    where T : MainWindowModel
{
    private static MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public ListViewItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public string MyTitle
    {
        get => _model.WindowTitle;
        set => _model.WindowTitle = value;
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(T model) : base(model)
    {
        ResidentListControlViewModel.ResidentChanged += ResidentListControlViewModel_ResidentChanged;
        MyTitle = "Example";
    }

    static MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _mainWindow = (MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
    }
    private void ResidentListControlViewModel_ResidentChanged(object sender, ResidentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTitle = e.NewSelectedResidentName;
    }

    public static void SwitchScreen(object sender)
    {
        var screen = (UserControl)sender;
        if (screen == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        _mainWindow.mainStackPanel.Children.Clear();
        _mainWindow.mainStackPanel.Children.Add(screen);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Model

```
    public class MainWindowModel : BaseIPOModel
{
    private string _windowTitle;

    public string WindowTitle
    {
        get => _windowTitle;
        set => Set(ref _windowTitle, value);
    }
}
```

Базовая модель реализует INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //Оповещение об изменении
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    /// <summary>Упрощает присваивание и обновление полей</summary>
    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

Создание MainWindow

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;

    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindow = new MainWindow(new MainWindowModel());

        _mainWindow?.Show();
    }
}
```

Сам MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static ElementSize MainStackPanelSize { get; set; }
    public MainWindow(MainWindowModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel<MainWindowModel>(model);
    }       
}
```

Для проверки привязки и обновления заменил TextBlock на TextBox. При вводе значения при дебаге отчетливо наблюдается реагирование на изменение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть получается так, что поле привязано, поле при инициализации окна выставляется и отображается на View. Само поле реагирует на изменения с формы, заходит в сеттер. Но при обновлении его из вьюмодели (там значение меняется) не обновляется отображаемый результат. В чем может быть причина? Есть в проекте по такому же шаблону еще один контрол со своей вью моделью, там все работает как надо.

Comment: @aepot, поправил

Comment: Вы не показали, к чему у вас привязан заголовок окна. Еще у вас грубое нарушение MVVM (это же MVVM?). Вьюмодель обращается к экземпляру окна.

Comment: @aepot Заголовок окна никуда не привязан. Свойство MyTitle в Binding у TextBox в первом куске кода из XAML. Про нарушение MVVM я в курсе, работаю над этим. Или это как то влияет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тайтл наверняка тоже привязан к `MyTitle`, но он не узнает о его изменении, если вы не вызовете `PropertyChanged` для этого свойства. Да и текстбокс не узнает, для него оно так же работает.

```cs
public string MyTitle
{
    get => _model.WindowTitle;
    set
    {
        _model.WindowTitle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

К тому же `UpdateSourceTrigger` влияет только на обновление свойства текстбоксом, а не наоборот.

Comment: Уведомление идет как раз в методе Set базовой модели. Там есть OnPropertyChanged. В дебаге туда все попадает. На скрине последнем видно.

Comment: @АртёмЕнин У вас тексбокс не к модели же привязан, а к вьюмодели, верно? Тогда почему вы решили что он отреагирует на изменения в модели?

Comment: Какой же я невнимательный)) Да, все верно. Вот оно, отсутствие практики..Не первый раз этим занимаюсь и в очередной раз на этом спотыкаюсь. Спасибо!